# Update Global Address Book in Roundcube Webmail 1.3.1 through backend

Tags: roundcube

I am using Roundcube Webmail 1.3.1 for our web mail solution.

I want to update the global address book table on a daily basis without changing the contact Id.

I want to update only the name field and the Vcard field of the contacts table.

Right now my structure is :

Name: Lalit Godara Emp no dept_details designation etc etc..

the dept and designation may change any time,

Thanks in advance.

Lalit

Comment: The global address book doesn't use a table on its own. It rather creates a new user_id with the name [globa_ addressbook_user] and uses that in the contacts table when adding new contacts.